# Poisson blending rgb out of range

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to blend two images using Poisson Blending technique. I have written the program and solved the system of linear equations separately for each r,g,b channel. After solving the equation rgb values are going out of bound, each value greater than 255. If I clamp each value to 255, the resulting image becomes white as all three channes are 255 now. My question is that can the rgb values be greater than 255 after solving poisson equation ? How can I have a proper blended image in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your scale for color values. According to the formula given in most of the online sites (set of equations), they consider the color value to be in the 0 to 1 range. Convert your 0 - 255 scale to floating point values between 0 - 1 and see.